# Jquery plugin fails after window loading

Tags: javascript, anomaly-detection, rateyo

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#additional_rating").rateYo({
            starWidth: "18px",
            rating: 4
        });
    };
    $("#quality_rating").rateYo({
        starWidth: "18px",
        rating: 4
    });
</script>
```

I can assure you that ids are correct. The problem is that, after the window loads, I get an error that rateYo is not a function. The second works. Could it be from a double loading, my other code, or I do something wrong there? It happened for other plugins too...

Comment: are you loading jQuery more than once on the page?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery.js more than once...either in different script tags or perhaps using ajax?

Comment: Why don't you use `$("#additional_rating, #quality_rating")` if you have the same options?

Comment: I removed jquery script load, and everything fails, which means there is just one script loaded.

Comment: @Ionut, I do the first rateYo later in code, and not in this context. I typed it like that just to show you the origin of error.

Comment: It would be great if you made a runnable snippet or a https://jsfiddle.net/ that would show the error you say you have. Otherwise people can take shots in the dark.

Comment: Removing the one jQuery.js is not conclusive that you aren't loading 2 versions such as one being loaded through ajax such as `$(selector).load(pageWithjQueryjs)` or the code shown is before a second version script tag. Using broser dev tools network would be better

Comment: Firstly, I copied, the jquery load script, and putted it directly on my page as first script. Result is the same. Second, I checked the ajax requests and everyone return json responses.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: @PopescuFlaviu, here, edit mine https://jsfiddle.net/q7L3fmne/ to reproduce the error :)

Comment: @Ionut, yeah, yours works... So there MUST be a double loading of any script in my code?

Comment: I did a search of `rateyo` in all my project, and there's no duplicates related to this page.

Comment: @charlietfl, nothing suspect in network tools.

Comment: Not looking for a duplicate of rateyo....looking for jQuery.js being loaded more than once

Comment: @charlietfl, I solved it in finally with a mate. The problem was pretty complicated. The jquery was somehow loaded again after page load cause a Laravel layout mistake in previous code. Thanks everyone tho.

Comment: And that should have been visible in dev tools network also